# How can I get a new line <br> in mvc @Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I get a new line 
 in a mvc ValidationSummary

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "asdfsadfsdf <br> sdfsdsddsfdfsdsf")


I want a new line instead of <br> in the output message
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code that you posted?

Comment: I want a new line instead of <br> in the message.

Comment: A newline isn't going to do you any good on a page. The text will still render on a single line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
   <div>
      @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(true, "asdfsadfsdf <br> sdfsdsddsfdfsdsf").ToHtmlString()))
   </div>
}
```